# How to load a xib inside uiview?

Tags: xcode, ipad

I'm working in an ipad splitview app  in which I have multiple IB elements now I added a `UISegmentedControl` and a UIView, what I want to do is when the `Segmentedcontrol` is switched the `uiview` should load and show another xibs that i have in my app. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NSBundle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSBundle_UIKitAdditions/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007485) to load a nib with your controller as the File's Owner. That gives you an easy way to load additional nib files and bind the views they contain to properties on your current controller. It will then be up to you to add those newly added views to your view hierarchy as appropriate for your app.

Comment: "Loading Custom Table-View Cells From Nib Files" (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW20) demonstrates loading a single UITableViewCell from a nib file. You could do the same but add the loaded view as a subview of some existing view rather than returning it from a datasource method which is specific to UITableViewDataSource.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSBundle to load the nib |